# Topmost Universal Gate Based Quantum Simulator?

Tags: qiskit, cirq

I am Elijah I'm interested in Drug Discovery and Materials Simulation. I want to purchase a gate based Quantum Simulator for research. I received a proposal.

- Full State Simulator 30 Qubits on Laptop, 40 Qubits on a 1U Rack. No GPU, No HDD, SWAP Space used.
- 100% accurate results within the usual limitations of measurement uncertainty and c128 precision.

My question is - I have been hearing for quite sometime that Nvidia QODA and ATOS QLM are the best Quantum Simulators in the world. How does the above compare with them?

[Update - I asked the Vendor to do a Live Benchmarking Exercise with me watching]

Here is the benchmark. Will post another update once I do a comparative benchmark with qsim.

[image]

Comment: At the very least you should compare with using a high performance open source simulator such as [qsim](https://github.com/quantumlib/qsim) on your laptop.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback Craig. I will post an update with qsim benchmarks soon. Let me know if it help readers help me make a choice between all the possible options, I believe there are 100's of them. I'm not an expert in quantum computing. Thanks for everything.

Comment: QODA is in waitlist. And I don't have access to an ATOS Appliance.

Comment: Can you share what specific benchmark, or type of benchmark,.you are using? I thought the world record of full state simulation is about 49 qubits. Given that 50 qubits consume just a quarter of a Gigabyte, instead of the 2^50*sizeof(complex) points to a sparse implementation which could potentially perform super bad on densely populated state vectors.